# Computing matrix from its eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could someone help me with solving this eigenvector question?
Thanks!

> Complete the $2\times2$ matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ so that $A$ has eigenvectors $v_1=[3~1]^T$ and $v_2=[-2~1]^T$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, **source**, possible strategies, **your current progress**, why the question is interesting or important, etc. Otherwise your question will likely be downvoted and closed by the community.

Comment: For a basic guide to typeset your math equations, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I have formatted your math this time. Let me know if this was not what you intended to ask.

Comment: Hint: $v_1$ is an eigenvector if $Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1$ for some $\lambda_1$. Compute $Av_1$. How to choose $\lambda_1$? What does it say on $x,y$?

Answer (score 1):

$Av_1 = \lambda_1 v_1\\
\begin{bmatrix} 3x + y\\3\end{bmatrix} = \lambda_1\begin{bmatrix} 3\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
\lambda_1 = 3\\
3x + y = 9$

Using similar logic we find that $\lambda_2 = -2$ and $-2x+ y = 4$

Leaving you with a system of two equations that you should be able to solve.

There is also a theorem that says that the trace of $A = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$ and the determinant of $A = \lambda_1\lambda_2$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$D=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 \\-2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ and let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$B=D^{-1}AD= \frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix} 3(2+x)-y &  -2(2+x)+y \\ 3(3-x)-y  &  -2(3-x)-y \end{bmatrix}$$
Now set the off diagonal elements of $A$ as zero to make $B$ as adiagonal matrix, get
$y=2(2+x), y=3(3-x)  \implies x=1, y=6$, this gives
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 6 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$